# Submit multiple FORMS as 1 combined form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a jQuery plug-in to implement an accordion wizard based on bootstrap. http://sathomas.me/acc-wizard/#prerequisites

One thing that is odd to me is that each Panel is wrapped in a `<form>` `</form>` and the JavaScript then looks for each `<form>` and adds a `Next` or `Back` button.

So when you get the the final/last Panel and try to Submit the Form...it only will post the data from the last form.

I am not sure how I can make it take the form fields from each panel and then submit them all on the last  form...This seems like a flaw in the design?

So my question is, is this even possible to have multiple forms and then have the last form submit all the data from all the forms combined?

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can create a new in memory form `var form = $('<form action="..."></form>')` and then copy and append HTML from all forms on the page to this form `form.append($('form').children().clone())`. Then you can post in memory form `form.submit()`.

This solution can only work if you're able to override behavior of submit button on the last form.

Check this fiddle [Post all forms from page in one post jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCL52/1/)

Comment: Very cool.  Could you give me more of an example possibly on how to do the form fields>  I have probably 100 fields between 11 Forms in my wizard

Comment: Sorry my original solution had some bugs, I fixed them and I attached fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ZCL52/1/). Let me know if it works for you.